# What is happening in the title sequence of "About Elly"?

Tags: plot-explanation, title-sequence, about-elly

At the very beginning of "About Elly", during the titles, we seem to be seeing some sort of papers being shoved through some sort of slot – from the inside of whatever they're being shoved into.  What are we seeing?  Are those letters being inserted into a letter slot in a door?  Or ballots being put in a ballot box?  Or something else?  And what significance does it have to the rest of the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this review](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1360860/reviews?filter=chrono) on IMDB, the Director explained at the launch Q+A that the opening scene depicted the Iranian custom of placing folded banknotes into an [alms box](http://www.pbase.com/image/158605175) before traveling.

> ***Farhadi explained it was an alms box that travelers put money in
>   before a trip to ask for a safe trip, and yes, there was some dialog
>   about Elly putting money in an alms box, but I never connected it to
>   the opening scene.***

Answer (score 2):

As an Iranian person, I should answer this.
In Iran, we have some boxes in streets and roads that called 'Sandogh-e Sadaghe'. They Supported from government organizations. we put money on it to help poor peoples. 
there is an old belief that if you help to poor before a travel, you will be safe while you on it.
[image]